# How to send bulk emails using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am working on SAAS based project. Previously, I have used SES for sending transactional emails. Now I wanted to send personalized marketing emails to thousands of subscribers from a mailing list.

I have checked the following API operations:

```
- SendEmail:
    - Emails can be sent to 50 recipients per api request including to/cc/bcc. 
    - But in this I can't send personalized emails.
    - http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/ses/latest/ses-api.pdf#API_SendEmail
- SendBulkTemplatedEmail:
    - I can send personalized emails in batches to recipients and get unique message id for each recipient.
    - But here I am bound to use the email template created by SES CreateTemplate api operation. There is a limit of 10K email templates per Amazon SES account. As per my requirement I would like to create templates on my own.
    -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-api.html
```

None of above seems to fit for my requirement. Can you please guide how AWS can help me with this requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you need more than 10,000 email templates? Or that `CreateTemplate` does not meet your requirements? If so, what are your template requirements?

Comment: I am building my own html templates to send as emails. Moreover 10,000 email templates is a fix number that does not fit when we scale.

Comment: Why not create the SES Template when you need to send email and then delete it once you've finished? This way your app manages its own templates and you treat SES as a runtime concern.